# how to display ckeditor data in html in angular6

Tags: html, ckeditor, angular6

I want to display data from database (using PHPMYADMIN). The data which I want to display stored using ng2-ckeditor (Angular 6). So when it gives result it also shows the html tags, which I don't want. How do I get my result without displaying HTML tags?

This is for displaying in html page

(and  `newsArray` is type Object)
which is displaying data but with html tags

```
   <div *ngFor="let item of newsArray">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                      {{item.details}}
                    </div>   
   </div>
```

result given by this is:

```
<p>hello</p>
```

but expected result:

```
hello
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use [innerHtml] property on the div

```
<div *ngFor="let item of newsArray">
                    <div class="panel-body" [innerHtml]='item.details'>

                    </div>   
   </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can replace your result like this:

```
getText() {
  return this.data.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');
}
```

This will replace all your html tags and keep only the blank text.

See my [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sceju9)